# increasing heap size in java program gives problem

Tags: java

i am using a java program which requires a lot of ram. ( Ideally i would want to give it

10 GB of ram )

this program is run using a bat file. which has the following command to set java heap size

```
java  -Xmx896m weka.gui.explorer.Explorer
```

which allocates it `896 MB`.

I am running this program on a high end 64bit server with windows 2003 64bit standard OS.

when i try to change the bat file to increase heap size to lets say 1.8 GB by using

```
java  -Xmx1896m weka.gui.explorer.Explorer
```

it gives an error message  - `"Could not reserve enough space for object heap "` and the program doesnt start

how can i give this program a greater heap size atleast upto `4 GB`

Comment: The error message was "Could not reserve enough space for object heap"

Comment: error message is Could not reserve enough space for object heap "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using `-d64` to specify JVM to use 64 bit version?

```
java -d64 -Xmx2g weka.gui.explorer.Explorer
```

Just for information, that error should raise when JVM is trying to call `mmap` function to obtain the address space for the heap from operating system with an invalid size.

Comment: -d64 -Xmx?g is a must, also you can try -server

Comment: IIRC, JVM uses -d64 on 64-bit machines by default (at least my JVM had to be passed -d32 to try using 32-bit mode, and it failed)

Comment: this is the error i get on adding -d64,
" This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version. "

Comment: this means that despite OS on that machine is a 64 bit one the JDK installed is 32 bit, you should reinstall it choosing a 64 version.